# Index of Instance in Instances

Tags: java, indexing, weka, k-means

I use the Weka library for K-Means and I decided to change distance function between `Instance i1` and `Instance i2`, which is contained in dataset `Instance data`. How do I get the index of `i1` and `i2` in `data`?

[Weka API](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Instance.html) here. I can't find it.

Comment: There is an `int index(int position)` method. Does that not do what you need it to?

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai I have already tested it, so I decided it is not what I need, because I need to know this position. But how can I understand this position when it's the parameter of `index` function?

Comment: Have you tried `classIndex()`?

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai yes, but I need to set `data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1)`, but **k-means** don't supported Class